# Appropriate smart pointer for composition

Tags: c++, inheritance, smart-pointers

I have an inherited structure for a class:

```
struct A {
    ObjectByValue obv;
};

struct B : A {
    OtherThings ot;
};
```

And another class that wants a pointer to `A`:

```
struct C {
    smartpointer<A> a;
};
```

When I create `C`, I pass in an already created `B` (as a pointer to `A`).  `C` doesn't OWN `A` (and a `C` without an `A` doesn't make any sense).  `C` will (hopefully) always die before the `A` pointer is freed.  Should I use a smart pointer?  A reference?  A raw pointer?  Is there a best practice here?

Comment: The question you have to answer is *who owns A*. That determines entirely what pointer to use.

Comment: @nneonneo:  So, if A is not owned by anyone (maybe "main"?), then what would I want?

Comment: Who else is using `a`, is it only `C`. Or are there others? why not have `C` just create an `a`?

Comment: @Ben: because then `C` would have to cary around `B`'s instead of `A`'s.

Comment: @AndrewSpott, not true, you could still use a pointer or a unique pointer and instantiate a `B` and equate it to an `a`, i am just saying why not have `c` create the memory for that pointer? Or is `a` being used in something else which prohibits this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer depends strongly on *what* owns the `A` instance.

- If "nobody" owns the `A` instance, then it must be global or statically allocated. In that case, you should use a plain reference (`A&`). This also asserts that the object can never be null (i.e. it always exists for the lifetime of the `C`).

Otherwise, the object is dynamically allocated:

- If some other object owns the `A` instance, and can be proven to outlive the `C`, then the situation is pretty similar to the statically-allocated case. The owner should have a `unique_ptr<A>`, and `C` can have a plain reference.
- If some other object owns the `A` instance, but may or may not outlive `C`, then the owner should use a `shared_ptr<A>` and `C` should use a `weak_ptr<A>`. If the owner is deleted before `C` is, then the `weak_ptr` will automatically become null.
- If ownership should be *shared* between the `C` instance and some other owner, then you should use a `shared_ptr<A>` in both places. Then, the `C` instance guarantees that its `A` member is always valid, and shares ownership (in the sense that all owners must be deleted before the `A` will be deleted).

Comment: I think you have leapt to using `shared_ptr` too eagerly. If some other object has unique ownership of a dynamically-allocated `A` instance and will outlive `C` then that class should use a `unique_ptr` and `C` should use a pointer or reference. I would only resort to a `shared_ptr`/`weak_ptr` combination if the lifetimes are less clear.

Comment: @ChrisDrew: Thanks for the feedback. I'll work that into the answer.